# Windows phone 8 apps Image pinch/zoom in data template using canvas

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-8, pinchzoom

Windows Phone 8 apps i am using image in pivot control inside data template and then using pinch/zoom image But My Problem is if i am minimize image so small then it not zooming image..How to use canvas in data template.

---

MY XAML

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="pivot" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  Name="title" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Text="{Binding _textview}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" Foreground="Orange"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image  Margin="0,-30,0,80"  Name="img" Stretch="Fill"  Source="{Binding _images}"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" />
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                        <toolkit:GestureListener PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta" DoubleTap="GestureListener_DoubleTap" DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta"  />
                    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</phone:Pivot>
```

---

MY CS

```C#
private void OnPinchStarted(object sender, PinchStartedGestureEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image;
    var transform = image.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    angle = transform.Rotation;
    scale = transform.ScaleX;
}

private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image;
    var transform = image.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    transform.Rotation = angle + e.TotalAngleDelta;
    transform.ScaleX = scale * e.DistanceRatio;
    transform.ScaleY = scale * e.DistanceRatio;
}

private void GestureListener_DoubleTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image;
    var transform = image.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    transform.ScaleX = transform.ScaleY = 1;
}

private void GestureListener_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image;
    var transform = image.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    transform.TranslateX += e.HorizontalChange;
    transform.TranslateY += e.VerticalChange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you need to show an image in canvas,

```XAML
<Canvas>
    <Image  Margin="0,-30,0,80"  Name="img" Stretch="Fill"  Source="{Binding _images}"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

For further reference, here is a [great official sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/image-recipes-0c0b8fee)

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent pinching the image too small by limiting the scale to a minimum size.

```
// Don't shrink the image to less than 1/4 normal size.
const double minScaleX = 0.25;
const double minScaleY = 0.25;

private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image;
    var transform = image.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    transform.Rotation = angle + e.TotalAngleDelta;
    transform.ScaleX = scale * e.DistanceRatio;
    transform.ScaleY = scale * e.DistanceRatio;

    if (transform.ScaleX < minScaleX) 
    {
        transform.ScaleX = minScaleX;
    }
    if (transform.ScaleY < minScaleY) 
    {
        transform.ScaleY = minScaleY;
    }
}
```